# Types error when calling 2 functions inside a map

Tags: scala, function, lambda, anonymous-function

I'm quite new to Scala and trying to analyze some nice functional code for some exercises like below:

```
    object ArmstrongNumbers {
      def isArmstrongNumber(num: Int): Boolean = {
        val digits_str = num.toString  
        val charToDigit: Char => Int = _.asDigit
    
        digits_str.map(charToDigit andThen math.pow(_, digits_str.size)).sum
      }
    }
```

This raises quite a confusing error for me:

*"Found:    Double*

*Required: Int => Any*

*No implicit Ordering defined for B*

*where:    B is a type variable with constraint >: Char => Nothing*
*."*

I can make this working by declaring power function beforehand like this:

```
    val power: Int => Double = math.pow(_, digits_str.size)
    num == digits_str.map(digitialize andThen power).sum()
```

or by surrounding it with {}:

```
    val a = digits_str.map(charToDigit andThen {math.pow(_, digits_str.size)}).sum
```

but wanted to understand the internals of Scala working and how to read these kind of errors. Can someone please explain step by step what the error means and actually what change {} make here?

Comment: Personal advice, stay away of the underscore syntax and don't try to write fancy code, especially related to functions. Is way better to write something simple like: `c => math.pow(x.asDigit, digits_str.size)`

Answer (score 2):

One of the usages of `_` is to represent an anonymous function placeholder parameter, i.e. `"digits_str".map(_ + '1')` is the same as `"digits_str".map(x => x + '1')`. Compiler treats `_` in `math.pow(_, digits_str.size)` as anonymous function placeholder parameter of enclosing function passed to `map`, so `math.pow(_, digits_str.size)` is evaluated as `Double` and not a function accepting `Int` and returning something, hence the error.
The workarounds make the compiler treat `_` as partial function application resolving the issue.